# Formatting date using Angular

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

Why the following code produces strange output (looks like moment().valueOf() returns 0)

```
Since 7 days ago : {{(moment().valueOf()  - 7*24*60*60*1000)  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

returns

```
Since 7 days ago : 1969-12-25
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you explained what you are trying to achieve. Even though I believe you are looking for something like this: 

`moment(moment().valueOf()  - 7*24*60*60*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`. You can bind this directly, without using AngularJS `dateFilter`.

**EDIT:** Bixi's answer is definitely clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with moment API :

```
moment().subtract('days', 7).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/D9UCF/1/

Comment: Thanks Bixi, don't know why nothing shows up when I try it! Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D9UCF/

Comment: Added fiddle. You can't use moment() like that in a template. One solution is to use a scope variable. Another one is to use a dedicated angular moment module like https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: May I know what it can't be used like that?

Comment: in angular template expressions you have to use angular mechanisms such as filters, operators, scope variable, etc ... see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: As a simple solution, you can expose `moment` trough the scope: `$scope.moment = moment` and I guess it would make your example work. Anyway, better to encapsulate the library in a dedicated service. See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/D9UCF/3/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because:

> moment#valueOf simply outputs the number of milliseconds since the
>   Unix Epoch, just like Date#valueOf.

[[http://momentjs.com/docs/]](http://momentjs.com/docs/%5d)

One way to achieve what you want is as follows:

```
Since 7 days ago: <span ng-bind="sevenDaysAgo"></span>

$scope.sevenDaysAgo = moment(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7))).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: yeah, moment().valueOf() returns a number whilst angular's date filter works with Date objects